# unrecognized arguments: in PyTest

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

I am unable to generate a html report in pytest. I have installed `pytest --html` without any issue.

When i tried to run

```
 py.test --html=report.html
```

getting unrecognized arguments error. I've surfed internet a lot everyone is telling `pytest --html` might not installed but in mu case everything been installed still getting that error message.

I tried installing package in PyCharm as well didn't worked

Comment: By installed `pytest --html` you mean `pytest-html`, right? Also, don't use the long deprecated `py.test`, use `pytest` instead.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes you are right. I tried pytest --html=report.html also not working.

Comment: Please show the output of your test, at least the start, where it lists the installed plugins - just to be sure that `pytest-html` is installed.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Please see the output as you asked,
C:\Users\naveen.kstb\PycharmProjects\PythonTesting\pytestDemo> pip list
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
pip                  22.3.1
py                   1.11.0
pycodestyle          2.10.0
pycparser            2.21
pytest               7.2.0
pytest-cache         1.0
pytest-forked        1.4.0
pytest-html          3.2.0
pytest-html-reporter 0.2.9

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Also same command tried my colleagues machine worked fine but he has python 3.9. Could be issue with python 3.11?

Comment: It is unlikely that this has to do with Python 3.11. Can show how you start pytest? Or do you start it only inside PyCharm? If yes, please try to run it at the command line and show the output (please add this to the qustion, not to the comments). Also make sure that the Python environment configured in PyCharm is the one you show.